# Seeing which Gouie spoke in the hippopotamus language

Tags: pronouns

*Keo recognized the scent of a black man and tried to raise his head high enough to bite him. **Seeing which** Gouie spoke in the hippopotamus language, which he had learned from his grandfather, the sorcerer:
"Have peace, little one; you are my captive."*

Source: https://americanliterature.com/author/l-frank-baum/short-story/the-laughing-hippopotamus

I found the usage of "which" in the sentence above a little bit odd. If there were "it" this would make more sense: When he saw **it**, Gouie spoke… But why "which"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Seeing which**, Gouie spoke...

Seeing *that aforementioned thing*, Gouie spoke...

> There was a car broken down on the shoulder ahead being hauled up onto
>   a tow truck, seeing which, he moved into the outer lane.

The use of **which** in this way is related to the following use, with which you are no doubt more familiar:

> There was  a stew simmering on the burner, the smell of **which** made him
>   very hungry.

I suspect that what is confusing you in the original is the participle, in light of which, I offer this paraphrase:

> Keo recognized the scent of a black man and tried to raise his head
>   high enough to bite him, **in light of** which, Gouie spoke in the
>   hippopotamus language, which he had learned from his grandfather...

You're familiar with the use of **which** as the object of a preposition (*the smell of which*, *in light of which*) and now you understand that **which** can also be the object of a verb. It is a somewhat dated use.

> He felt the weight of the shillings|silver dollars in his pocket, having which, he decided to stop by the pub|saloon for a beer.

Comment: No, the participle does not confuse me at all. It is just the use of "which" which very often indicates the relative clause but I did not know to which noun is "which" in my sentence related.

Comment: I tried with my first example to show you that it does not relate necessarily to a single noun but to "that aforementioned thing" -- it can be an *action* or *activity* occurring or *fact* presented in the prior clause, as is also the case with **in light of which**.